# Setting correct units for timedelta in python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timedelta

I have a pandas dataframe that contains information about days and times for specific items. However, the times are not synced to the correct local time (they are in EST).
I have the following code:

```
date_obj = pandas.to_datetime(train_data["DAY"], format = '%m/%d/%Y')
time_obj = pandas.to_datetime(train_data["TIME"], format = '%H:%M:%S')
train_data["TIME_OFFSET"] = (-1*(train_data["Time_Zone"] == "CST") - 2*(train_data["Time_Zone"] == "MST") - 3*(train_data["Time_Zone"] == "PST") - 4*(train_data["Time_Zone"] == "AKST") - 5*(train_data["Time_Zone"] == "HST") )*60

time_delta = pandas.to_timedelta(train_data["TIME_OFFSET"] )  
print(time_obj)
print(time_delta)
time_obj = time_obj + time_delta
```

However, this is not doing what I want, and I assume because I did not set the correct units for the timedelta, so my time_delta is very small.

How do I set things correctly?

Comment: Please include an example, `train_data.head()` should suffice.

Comment: I could multiply by 3600000000000 instead of 60, and this fixes the issue, but I would like to know the *correct* way to fix this.

Comment: As I wrote, without an example we can't help you.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/), it's a very useful library to work with timezones